# Transact SQL Finding Max Registration in each Group

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2000

Good Morning All.

I have a table structure (I am using SQL SERVER 2000)

**CourseID    StudentName  TermPaperID**

```
101         Jon            1   
101         Jon            2
101         Jon            3
101         David          1   
101         David          2
102         David          5 
102         David          6 
102         George         5
```

I would  like to list out CourseID,StudentName,Maximum registration per Course.

I tried the following Query

```
select 
CourseId,
StudentName,
max(x.numberofregistration) as max_registration
from
(
   select 
           CourseID,
           StudentName,
           count(CourseID) as numberofregistration 
    from 
    dbo.Students 
            group by CourseId,StudentName
 )x
 group by CourseId,StudentName
```

but it did no give the expected result.

The expected result is
I have a table structure

**CourseID    StudentName  max_registration**

```
101         Jon            3   
102         David          2
```

How to achieve the expected result? Thanks in advance.

Comment: SQL Server 2000? I feel bad for you, but why?

Comment: if there was another row: "102, George, 5" how would you expect this to impact the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a really, really ugly way. I think I'd rather pony up the upgrade fee than write too many of these. Hopefully someone else will come up with something cleaner.

```
CREATE TABLE #x(CourseID INT, StudentName VARCHAR(32), TermPaperID INT);

INSERT #x SELECT 101,'Jon   ',1;   
INSERT #x SELECT 101,'Jon   ',2;
INSERT #x SELECT 101,'Jon   ',3;
INSERT #x SELECT 101,'David ',1;   
INSERT #x SELECT 101,'David ',2;
INSERT #x SELECT 102,'David ',5; 
INSERT #x SELECT 102,'David ',6; 
INSERT #x SELECT 102,'George',5;

SELECT b.CourseID, b.StudentName, max_registration = COUNT(*)
FROM #x AS b
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT CourseID, c = MAX(c)
  FROM
  (
    SELECT CourseID, StudentName, c = COUNT(CourseID) 
    FROM #x GROUP BY CourseID, StudentName
  ) AS x GROUP BY CourseID
) AS s
ON b.CourseID = s.CourseID
GROUP BY b.CourseID, b.StudentName
HAVING COUNT(*) = MAX(s.c)
ORDER BY b.CourseID;
```

Comment: thank you very much for spending your time to guide me. I do agree using row_number() and Partition we can easily resolve this,but i am working on client side project where in they are still using SQL Server 2000.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your CTE 'x' is grouping by the same value as the one you are counting.  Simply counting a different field (ie, term paper id) should provide the expected results.

That being said, in your desired results sample, I'm not clear why those results are expected from the sample data.  If I've misunderstood the question, I'll be happy to try again! :-)